# SignalR 2 Client - Data Serialization Issues

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, serialization, signalr

I am currently developing a Visual Studio VSIX extension with SignalR support and I am running into a strange issue.

Here is the strongly-typed hub code:

```
public interface ISyncClient
{
    void SelectionChanged(SelectionChangedMessage message);
}

public class SyncHub: Hub<ISyncClient>
{
    public void SelectionChanged(SelectionChangedMessage message)
    {
        Clients.Others.SelectionChanged(message);
    }
}
```

And here is the message class:

```
public class SelectionChangedMessage
{
    [JsonProperty("ss")]
    public int SelectionStart { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("se")]
    public int SelectionEnd { get; set; }
}
```

The hub and the client communicate properly. On the client I have the following code:

```
proxy.On("selectionChanged", m => { var selectionStart = m.ss; });
proxy.On<SelectionChangedMessage>("selectionChanged", m => { var selectionStart = m.SelectionStart; });
```

The first handler receives the dynamic object and the ss property (SelectionStart) is present.
The second handler however, has the SelectionStart property with a default value.

The messages, which are passing through the hub have their values set, but whenever the client tries to deserialize the message to the concrete message type it fails.

Somehow the client can't properly deserialize the JsonProperty attributes.

The client and the server are running SignalR 2.2.1 with Newtonsoft.Json 9.0.1.

The same code works with a SignalR 2.2.1 client and a SignalR 0.1.0 Server from [aspnetmaster](https://www.myget.org/feed/aspnetmaster/package/nuget/Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Server) running on ASP.NET Core.

Has anyone else ran into similar issues?

**Edit**

I did a clean rebuild and made sure that all projects use the same version of Newtonsoft.Json. I also reset the Visual Studio Experimental instance and all started working.

Comment: When you say it fails, does it throw any errors?

Comment: No, it didn't throw errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did a clean rebuild and made sure that all projects use the same version of Newtonsoft.Json. I also reset the Visual Studio Experimental instance and all started working.

Comment: Hey Nikolay, have you encountered any issues with hosting SignlaR in the VS extension? Here's what I mean: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73843517/signalr-hosted-in-a-visual-studio-extension  Thanks!